# Avoiding the select a store option when placing orders

Tags: orders, magento-enterprise, administration

I have a Magento EE site with two store views, the default store and a mobile store. When creating orders in the admin I would like to skip the step that asks the user to select a store, e.g. all orders would be placed under the default store.

**Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Create_Form::getStoreSelectorDisplay()**:

```
     $storeId    = $this->getStoreId();
     $customerId = $this->getCustomerId();
     if (!is_null($customerId) && !$storeId) {
         return 'block';
     }
     return 'none';
```

It looks like if I add `$this->setStoreId(1)` in the constructor (or somewhere) then the store selector will never be displayed and the order will be created under the store of my choosing. My question is, is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

If you change the action for the "Create order" button and add the store_id parameter it will skip the form.

Normally the button to create an order for a client links to:
`/index.php/admin/sales_order_create/index/customer_id/6/`

This will show you the store selector, so if you change the action to:
`/index.php/admin/sales_order_create/index/customer_id/6/store_id/1/`

This will select the specified store and brings you directly to the order form.

The same can be done on the "Create New Order" button in the Sales->Orders grid, if you add store_id there it only asks you to select the customer (or create a new customer)

Comment: Actually in my version the Create Order button links to 'sales_order_create/start/...', which resets the quote and does not pass along a store_id parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by overriding Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Store\Select and adding setStoreId instruction in the constructor like this:

```
protected function _construct() {
  parent::_construct();
  // Allowing passing commades in BO for website 1 solely
  $this->setStoreIds([1]);
  $this->setId('sc_store_select');
 }
```